# How do we sequence tenses in questions?

Tags: tense

> Have you ever fallen down and got hurt?

I wish to know if this is correct usage of tense. Specifically, is the sequence of tenses okay?

Comment: "fallen down and gotten hurt"

Answer (score 1):

The tenses are correct, as is the sequence.

(You could also switch the sequence, but then you'd have to rephrase a bit to say that you got hurt *because* you fell down.)

Note that in the United States, both [*have* ***got*** and *have* ***gotten***](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/difference-between-have-got-and-have-gotten) can be used as the past participle of *get*. I believe that *have gotten* is more common, at least informally, but neither is wrong. In the UK, there is no such word at *gotten*—so, only *have got* is correct. (As a Canadian, I have seen and heard both. I would probably lean a little more toward *have got*—I have a more British-informed past—but am also comfortable with *have gotten*.)